# Compiling code from command line with Visual Studio compiler, how to change the icon of .exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, icons, exe

I know that normally I should just open the Visual Studio project and change the icon from Resource view.
My problem is, I don't have a Visual Studio project. I wrote my code in a custom text editor, and I compile it with Visual Studio using "cl" command from a batch file.

How do I link the .rc file to change the icon of the .exe file that the VS compiler outputs?

I searched visual studio compiler options but found nothing. Should I just use another compiler? Is it any easier using g++?

Here's my batch file if it helps:

```
@echo off
if not defined DevEnvDir (
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
)
mkdir ..\build
pushd ..\build
cl -Zi /I ..\code\dependencies\include\SDL /I ..\code ..\code\*.cpp user32.lib ..\code\dependencies\lib\SDL2.lib ..\code\dependencies\lib\SDL2main.lib ..\code\dependencies\lib\SDL2_image.lib /link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
popd
```

Comment: Create a `.rc` resource file with the icon, use `rc.exe` to convert it to a `.res` file, then use the linker to link the `.res` file to  your program.

Comment: @sharyex Thank you

Comment: @sharyex It is better to answer the question with a formal answer rather than in the comments.